# Using dependency injection to make store available to all models in ember app

Tags: ember.js

I'm using ember **without ember data**, with a store based on this: https://github.com/eviltrout/emberreddit/blob/master/app/models/store.js

I'm trying to use dependency injection in order to make the store accessible in my models but this doesn't seem to work:

```
Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true

Ember.Application.initializer
  name: 'injectStore'
  initialize: (container, app) ->
    app.register('store:main', App.Store)
    app.inject('route', 'store', 'store:main')
    app.inject('controller', 'store', 'store:main')
    app.inject('model', 'store', 'store:main')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of this may seem completely ridiculous when you read it, but I promise that it does work. I've been using it in my Ember-Data alternative since February.

```
Em.onLoad('Ember.Application', function(Application) {
    Application.initializer({
        name: 'injectStore',
        before: 'store',

        initialize: function(container, App) {
            App.inject('model', 'store', 'store:main');
        }
    });

    Application.initializer({
        name: 'store',

        initialize: function(container, App) {
            App.register('store:main', App.Store, { singleton: true });
        }
    });
});
```

However, please note that this will only work **if the container instantiates your models**. If you create the model by using `create()`, I don't think the store will be injected properly. (Maybe that's your current problem?) I don't use the container to instantiate my models, I use the store, so I do something like this:

```
    createRecord: function(typeKey, json) {
        var record = ...

        record.set('store', this);
    }
```

Comment: Awesome, so the problem was exactly what you described, i.e using the container to instantiate the model. Creating via the store is working now. Thanks for your help!